# Interface Builder's inspectors are completely empty

Tags: xcode, xcode7, inspector

I am using XCode 7.0.1 and I am facing a strange problem: All inspectors (except identitiy and quick help) are completely empty:

[image]

This happened after I had checked out an old commit and switched back to HEAD. Has anybody else observed this behaviour? This already happened a few days ago. Back then, I was able to solve this problem only by reinstalling XCode entirely. Since this requires a redownload of XCode by Appstore I am facing a really long coffee break now.

What is wrong with XCode?

Comment: Ditto with me running Xcode 7.2.  Possible solution: close xib tab and relaunch Xcode to access XIB.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I found the workaround here:

http://embraceware.com/blog/2015/09/solution-for-no-selection-in-xcode-interface-builder/

TLDR: Close all storyboard tabs, open a new one.